# Reliable way to find application icons?

Tags: icons, qt, c++

I'm creating an app in Qt Creator and C++ that lists all apps on the system by indexing `.desktop` files from `/usr/share/applications` and `~/.local/share/applications`. In almost every icon path, I don't get the actual path I get instead a local path, like in the instance of the Characters application where the icon path is simply `org.gnome.Characters`.

I've heard that icons are typically found in `/usr/share/pixmaps`, but I looked for that icon and it wasn't present. I did a search over my entire system and found multiple instances, most of which were in `/usr/share/icons/Yaru` (aka an icon theme pack).

I could index over the theme packs as places to search for icons but this is unreliable for two reasons:

1. If I crawl a directory and its subdirectories for the first match of an icon in an icon pack, I might get a lower resolution image if there are multiple different resolutions supported.
2. The user might have uninstalled the theme.

That was a bunch of hassle for just one icon. Is there a better way to do this? Since I don't have the full path of the icon I think I'm pretty much left with indexing tons of spots for the icon, which is unnecessary processing.

Is there a good way to do this, and are there other icon locations I should be checking? Maybe a Qt function that locates the icon based on the local path :)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really Ubuntu-related since it's a Qt programming question, but still...

In this case, use [QIcon::fromTheme()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#fromTheme-1). That uses the desktop's theme path which is what a user also sees in the desktop's menus.

There is an overloaded version where you can supply a fallback icon in case the desktop theme cannot provide the icon.

For my own icons in my [QDirStat](https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat), I use compiled-in icons using the [Qt resource system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) so I don't have to rely on my luck whether or not any icon is available; and also to make sure they all have a consistent look and feel in case some icons are in the theme, and some are not.

But in your case, you want to display the icons of *other* applications, so the theme icons are the first place to load them from. Notice that you may have several icon themes installed which all overlap to some extent, so letting the desktop decide which theme to use is the way to go; otherwise you will very likely pick an icon from a wrong icon theme.

Comment: That worked really well for me, thanks! It works on about 80% of icons for me and I can use your other method to have pre-compiled icons as well.